# Name of isometric invariant in Gauss-Bonnet

Tags: differential-geometry

Does the tangential rotation term $ \int k_g ds $ of Gauss-Bonnet theorem ( for continuous or discontinuous lines on a surface) have a name or symbol in differential geometry ?

The second term $ \int K dA $ integral curvature and the topological invariant  Euler characteristic have identifiable names.

EDIT1:

$ \int k_g ds $, the 'Boundary Rotation' if you will, is defined here for tangent developable Frills with zero Gauss curvature. They are  $ 2 \pi $ for flat disc rim, 4 EllipticE(-1/2) for the Viviani Frill and favorite 'Twisted Frill1' of mine, 8 EllipticE(-1/4).They are tangential to the North-South Polar axis. Can be made by cutting and pasting flexible rings of Boundary Rotation $ >2 \pi.$

Appreciate anyone coming up with paper/thin plastic models to post it here.

[image: TwoFrills]

Comment: Total boundary curvature.

Comment: A curvature should have dimension 1/L, so may I borrow a part of your suggestion for it as 'boundary rotation'?

Comment: I included two Frills born out of discussions much earlier in sci.math ng.

Comment: "Total curvature" is the conventional name for the integral of geodesic curvature along a curve, so "total boundary curvature" seems correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_curvature